# Printing the same Word document on the same printer from two PCs gives different results in colour

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, printer, colors

One of my co-workers has created a Word document based on our company template (basically a stylized blueish background image). If she prints this document, the blue colour is very light and hardly visible. If another co-worker prints the exact same document on the same printer, the blue colour is as it should be (light but clearly visible).

We are all using Office 365.

What could possibly be the cause for these different printing results?

Thanks in advance for suggestions as to where to start.

edit: it's perhaps worth noting that it's not an issue with this particular document only. All documents have the same company template, and the issue is the same for all documents.

Comment: Have you tried to convert it to PDF and print the PDF version?

Comment: Check that the printer settings are the same on both machines. One could be set to draft quality or other colour settings. Just because you are printing to the same place does not mean the print settings (printer properties) are the same.

Comment: @mTorres: converting the document to PDF and printing the PDF version gives the same results, the background is hardly visible.

Comment: @Mokubai: the printer settings all look okay to me, they are identical on both machines as far as I can see.

Comment: Try to check ICC profiles.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the ICC profiles are the same on both machines.

Comment: Has anyone checked whether the correct printer-driver is installed?

Comment: @Cindy Meister: yes, I've checked, and the printer driver is the correct one. Even if it were not, the driver is the same for both computers so I would assume that the resulting prints would be the same regardless.

Comment: Actually, a different version of the printer driver can make a difference, which is why I asked...

Comment: @Cindy Meister: I agree that a different version of the printer driver can make a difference. What I meant was that both computers always have the same version of the printer driver installed. Therefor, if both computers had an incorrect version, they would still both behave the same imho.